# How to get first three created element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am creating some divs using Javascript. I need a total of 9! I used `for` loop like this:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i = i + 1) {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  let array = div
  div.className = 'box box'+ i
  if (i % 3 === 0)
    console.log(array)
}
```

I stored the elements in the variable called `array`. So, when `i = 3`, `array` should have `<div class="box box1"></div>`, `<div class="box box2"></div>` & `<div class="box box3"></div>`. Instead it gives me other results. I just want `<div class="box box1"></div>`, `<div class="box box2"></div>` & `<div class="box box3"></div>`.

Please help me fix this!

Comment: What result do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    let array = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i = i + 1) {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        array.push(div);
        div.className = 'box box'+ i;
        if (i % 3 === 0)
            console.log(array);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @DanielMöller !

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `document.createElement` like this. If you want to use it, first you have create a main `div` element and append your child elements to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

In order to build your array, you need to `push` each new element on to the end of the existing array.

**Working Example:**

```js
var myDiv;
var myArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

  myDiv = document.createElement('div');
  myArray.push(myDiv);
  myDiv.classList.add('box');
  myDiv.classList.add('box' + (i + 1));
}

console.log(myArray);
```